# The best way to achieve the requirement column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

What is the best way to achieve the requirement from the sample data as per the screenshot attached? I want to merge the RED highlighted font in one row & delete the additional Row. Example - Data in row 4, 6 & 8 can move to the previous column & then 4, 6 & 8 rows should be completely deleted.

Note: there is no consistency in data the inconsistency of data may very between ROWS like B4, C6 & A8.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delete Entire Rows With Condition

- Loops through the rows from the bottom to the top.
- If there is at least one blank cell, returns the value of each cell adjacent to the top of each non-blank cell, concatenated with the value of the non-blank cell, in the adjacent cell. Then it combines the first cell of the row into a range.
- Deletes the entire rows of the combined range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConcatMissing()
    
    Const SecondDataRowFirstCellAddress As String = "A4"
    Const Delimiter As String = ""
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(SecondDataRowFirstCellAddress)
    Dim rg As Range
    With fCell.CurrentRegion
        Set rg = fCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - fCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - fCell.Column)
    End With
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim rrg As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim SkipRow As Boolean
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = rg.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set rrg = rg.Rows(r)
        If Application.CountBlank(rrg) > 0 Then
            For Each rCell In rrg.Cells
                If Len(CStr(rCell.Value)) > 0 Then
                    rCell.Offset(-1).Value = CStr(rCell.Offset(-1).Value) _
                        & Delimiter & CStr(rCell.Value)
                End If
            Next rCell
            If drg Is Nothing Then
                Set drg = rrg.Cells(1)
            Else
                Set drg = Union(drg, rrg.Cells(1))
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    drg.EntireRow.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your help here.